# XIAOMI MI5 Notification is not working when App not is background?

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification

My app able to receive a push Notification when the app is not running on Motorola, Samsung, Sony, but Xiaomi with MI 5 unable to receive Notification if the app is not running.But WhatsApp Notification Working properly.Thanks in Advance .

Is there any problem in Xiaomi phones?

Here is my Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

And Notification Builder code

```
 NotificationManager mNotifyManager =
     (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new 
 NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
 mBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
 mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000});
 mBuilder.setContentText(object.get(ChatConstants.NOTIFICATION.BODY).toString())
 .setContentTitle(object.get(ChatConstants.NOTIFICATION.TITLE).toString())
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_splash)
                                .setAutoCancel(true).setSound(defaultSoundUri);
 mNotifyManager.notify(Request, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: I have faced same problem in Xiaomi. Turn on auto start property for your app  and then check again . Its inside Security app of Xiaomi device

Comment: The notification from Firebase works fine on my device. Any logs?

Comment: @ADM I have done this but still not getting, How WhatsApp Archive without any setting changes